# ExtJS4 / Sencha Touch 2: Reuse data (loaded into store) in different views with different sorting

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs4, extjs, datastore

I have data in an external database which can be accessed via JSON. Now I want to provide different views on these data sets (eg. different sorting, ..). Is it possible to use one single store for this or do I need two stores accessing the same URL except with a different sorter?

My example code looks like this:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.MyStore', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
requires: [
    'MyApp.model.MyModel'
],

config: {
    autoLoad: true,
    model: 'MyApp.model.MyModel',
    storeId: 'MyJsonStore',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'http://localhost/index.php?data=MyData&format=json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json'
        }
    },
    sorters: [
        {
            direction: 'DESC',
            property: 'MyRating'
        },
        {
            direction: 'ASC',
            property: 'MyLabel'
        }
    ] } });
```

And one view should now render a list sorted by the rating and a second one should display a list sorted by the label.

Is there a way to prevent querying the DB twice?

Thanks - I just started out with Sencha Touch and ExtJS --- therefore please excuse my simple question ;) 

Somehow I couldn't find any smart solution by asking Google for this basic task..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to worry about anything unless your two views are presented at the same time. Just re-sort the same store locally.

If they are presented at the same time you will have to create a copy of a store. Otherwise they will show exact same information.

Comment: Great - thanks! But how do I resort a store at runtime? (damn, is this a basic.. :D)

Comment: `store.sort()`? http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-sort

Comment: Ouch - I had the wrong object at hand while trying out. Thank you, works like a charm!